22.04.4 LTS snap firefox chromium permission problems
I'm running 22.04.4 LTS and Ubuntu Pro support enabled.
"Suddenly" my firefox and chromium stops to start.
If I try to launch them from terminal I get back this errors:
(base) pippo@Ganimede:~$ firefox
cannot create mount point for file "/tmp/snap.rootfs_vDF3Sz/README.md": Permission denied

(base) pippo@Ganimede:~$ chromium
cannot create mount point for file "/tmp/snap.rootfs_QFJXpv/README.md": Permission denied

I tried to refresh snap but it complete the operations with this message:
(base) pippo@Ganimede:~$ sudo snap refresh
[sudo] password for pippo: 
Download snap "firefox" (4090) from channel "latest/stable"    4%  772kB/s 47.7serror: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run post-refresh hook of "firefox" snap if present (run hook "post-refresh": cannot create mount point for file "/tmp/snap.rootfs_kHleRT/README.md": Permission denied)
- Run configure hook of "chromium" snap if present (run hook "configure": cannot create mount point for file "/tmp/snap.rootfs_IPuR2q/README.md": Permission denied)
(base) pippo@Ganimede:~$ 

If I go to read syslog file I can find those lines:
Apr  6 08:31:50 Ganimede systemd[4846]: Started snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software-de50015d-5d40-460b-be18-2447e2344f53.scope.
Apr  6 08:31:50 Ganimede snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop[11558]: cannot create mount point for file "/tmp/snap.rootfs_MwvIqr/README.md": Permission denied
Apr  6 08:31:50 Ganimede kernel: [ 3333.275378] kauditd_printk_skb: 57 callbacks suppressed
Apr  6 08:31:50 Ganimede kernel: [ 3333.275380] audit: type=1400 audit(1712385110.343:307): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=11558 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
Apr  6 08:31:50 Ganimede kernel: [ 3333.275385] audit: type=1400 audit(1712385110.343:308): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=11558 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
Apr  6 08:31:50 Ganimede kernel: [ 3333.276664] audit: type=1400 audit(1712385110.343:309): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/tmp/snap.rootfs_MwvIqr/README.md" pid=11558 comm="snap-confine" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0

It seems to me an Apparmor "problem" but..
I don't know what to do to fix those errors....
Some details on snap version and firefox and chromium snaps installed on my system:
(base) pippo@Ganimede:~$ sudo snap version
snap    2.61.3+22.04
snapd   2.61.3+22.04
series  16
ubuntu  22.04
kernel  5.15.0-101-generic
(base) pippo@Ganimede:~$

(base) pippo@Ganimede:~$ sudo snap info --verbose firefox
name:    firefox
summary: Mozilla Firefox web browser
health:
  status:  unknown
  message: health has not been set
publisher: Mozilla✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/firefox
contact:   https://support.mozilla.org/kb/file-bug-report-or-feature-request-mozilla
links:
  contact:
    - https://support.mozilla.org/kb/file-bug-report-or-feature-request-mozilla
  website:
    - https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/
license: unset
description: |
  Firefox is a powerful, extensible web browser with support for modern web application
  technologies.
commands:
  - firefox
  - firefox.geckodriver
notes:               
  private:           false
  confinement:       strict
  devmode:           false
  jailmode:          false
  trymode:           false
  enabled:           true
  broken:            false
  ignore-validation: false
base:         core22
snap-id:      3wdHCAVyZEmYsCMFDE9qt92UV8rC8Wdk
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: today at 08:00 CEST
channels:
  latest/stable:    124.0.2-1    2024-04-02 (4090) 281MB -
  latest/candidate: 124.0.2-1    2024-04-01 (4090) 281MB -
  latest/beta:      125.0b8-1    2024-04-03 (4102) 282MB -
  latest/edge:      126.0a1      2024-04-05 (4108) 302MB -
  esr/stable:       115.9.1esr-1 2024-03-22 (4032) 256MB -
  esr/candidate:    115.9.1esr-1 2024-03-22 (4032) 256MB -
  esr/beta:         ↑                                    
  esr/edge:         ↑                                    
installed:          124.0.1-1               (4033) 281MB -

(base) pippo@Ganimede:~$ sudo snap info --verbose chromium
name:    chromium
summary: Chromium web browser, open-source version of Chrome
health:
  status:  unknown
  message: health has not been set
publisher: Canonical✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/chromium
contact:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bugs?field.tag=snap
links:
  contact:
    - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bugs?field.tag=snap
  website:
    - https://code.launchpad.net/~chromium-team/chromium-browser/+git/snap-from-source
license: unset
description: |
  An open-source browser project that aims to build a safer, faster, and more
  stable way for all Internet users to experience the web.
commands:
  - chromium.chromedriver
  - chromium
notes:               
  private:           false
  confinement:       strict
  devmode:           false
  jailmode:          false
  trymode:           false
  enabled:           true
  broken:            false
  ignore-validation: false
base:         core22
snap-id:      XKEcBqPM06H1Z7zGOdG5fbICuf8NWK5R
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: today at 08:00 CEST
channels:
  latest/stable:    123.0.6312.105 2024-04-04 (2811) 168MB -
  latest/candidate: 123.0.6312.105 2024-04-03 (2811) 168MB -
  latest/beta:      124.0.6367.18  2024-04-02 (2809) 169MB -
  latest/edge:      125.0.6382.3   2024-04-02 (2810) 169MB -
installed:          123.0.6312.58             (2795) 168MB -
(base) pippo@Ganimede:~$ 

Many thanks and regards,
Arpagone

I have encountered a similar problem after a broken upgrade today. During an upgrade, one package (in my case libkcolorpicker-qt6-0) failed to install ("trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkColorPicker.so.0', which is also in package libkcolorpicker0:amd64 0.1.6-2"). I corrected this by removing one of the conflicting packages manually, and fixing the upgrade:
sudo dpkg --remove libkcolorpicker0
sudo apt --fix-broken install

This triggered a number of update scripts that had previously been stuck, including one for snapd which issued several warnings:
Setting up snapd (2.61.3+22.04) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real ...
snapd.failure.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Failed to restart snapd.mounts-pre.target: Operation refused, unit snapd.mounts-pre.target may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse manual start/stop).

After that, Firefox could be started as always. My interpretation of this is that, in the end, a snapd upgrade had not been completed properly, and the full set-up of the package finally solved the problem.
I am on KDE Neon 6.0, so my specific issues might not be yours, but the timing of the problem and the snapd version seem to match.
