Can't start any programs installed using Snap
Hi I'm trying to start Firefox or Chromium but it doesn't work. The Terminal says:
"cannot create mount point for file "/tmp/snap.rootfs_GHx5cA/README.md": Permission denied" and everytime I try to start Firefox a new folder appears in /tmp/
I'm using Kubuntu 22.04.4

did you try "sudo apt --fix-broken install" to see if there is any broken package pending? it may affect also your snaps if there is any pending post-inst script for snapd

It says "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded." And the kept back packages are "python3-update-manager update-manager-core"

do you see anything "snap" related in your "/var/log/syslog"?
you should also post the content of your "/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real", because it looks like that some users reporting snap-apps problem are having an older version of this file, like here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1509670/22-04-4-lts-snap-firefox-chromium-permission-problems

I don't see anything snap related in syslog. This is my /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real 

I did sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade and now it works. Did the same yesterday but it didn't work? I'm confused but atleast it works now lmao. It installed this

btw there is some difference between the last versione of that file and you version:
https://pastebin.com/eguTxCjw
curiously, a lot of differences regard snapd

Did Sudo Apt update and Sudo Apt upgrade and it fixed itself

probably some post-inst script regarding snapd was in standby and by doing apt upgrade you made it run and it fixed the permissions problem.

Had the same problem, after a sudo apt-get upgrade.
No snap app was starting anymore.
I solved the issue with
sudo apt --fix-broken install

(after a system reboot)
Thanks @AndreaTurbiglio
